# Using Haneke Objective-C Library in Swift File

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, haneke

Hey guys I've been having a hell of a time getting HanekeSwift into my swift app. I have just been getting errors that make no sense and all of the solutions I've found online don't work for me so I've decided to implement the Haneke Objective C library which I can successfully load into my project. I want to load a image url I am getting from the instagram api.

It will typically look like this: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12904980_852896554837748_1794074191_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTIyNTEyOTQ4MDY2MzE3OTEwMg%3D%3D.2

I a not very good at calling objective c classes in swift. Cant wrap my head around it. If anyone could help me call `[imageView hnk_setImageFromURL:url];`
 in swift using the objective c framework I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

**Edit**
I manged to get HanekeSwift to let me build a project without throwing an error. Current issue I'm having is that it will not recognize the framework when I call `import Haneke` it is throwing an error 'No such module Haneke'

Comment: Please mention the errors, and issues you are facing with Haneke?

Comment: `imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(url)`

Comment: imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(url)  throws the error : Value of type 'UIImage' has no member 'hnk_setImageFromURL' for me